# Netbeans & JUnit4 Shows No Test Running - Except when Run from Left Menu

Tags: java, junit, netbeans, junit4

I am currently trying to develop unit tests within Netbeans IDE 16 for Java, and encountering an issue I don't fully understand.

I am using Java platform 1.8 with Ant, with JUnit 4.13.2 and Hamcrest 1.3. When I create tests by following Tools > Create/Update Tests, I am given a new Test Package in the left hand-side with partially filled out test cases:

[image: File menu in netbeans]

I have then populated a very basic test to show here:

[image: A basic hello world test]

When I try to run this with Run > Test Project, it suggests no tests have been executed:

[image: No tests executed]

If I run the file individually, by clicking on them in the left hand menu and clicking 'Test File', it works fine:

[image]

Reading other guidance on Stackoverflow, it's suggested it could be project properties, version compatibility and/or human error. I'm very, very new to Java programming and a bit stumped, so hoping someone can help.

Comment: Yes, at least one problem you have is _"version compatibility"_, since running Java 8 on NetBeans 16 is unsupported. [From the Release Notes for NetBeans 16](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb16/): _"The Apache NetBeans 16 binary releases **require JDK 11+**, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17."_ So modify NetBeans to use Java 11 or Java 17, and then update your question if you still have problems.